# how to fix Archive Runner fail in flutter?

Tags: xcode, flutter

I made an app using a flutter and I want to distribute it to the app store. However, if I run  archive, It has fail.

flutter clean
flutter getpackage
flutter upgrade and update

product clean in xcode

but I has success product -> build

just when I distribute the app to archive. I got fails...

Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...
Dart snapshot generator failed with exit code -9
Building AOT snapshot in release mode (ios-release)...            309.0s (!)
Built to build/aot/.
Snapshotting (IOSArch.arm64) exited with non-zero exit code: -9
cp: build/aot/App.framework: No such file or directory
error: cannot parse the debug map for 'build/aot/App.framework/App': No such file or directory
Failed to generate debug symbols (dSYM) file for build/aot/App.framework/App.

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I solved this problem.

I made so many .dart files

so I spend a lot of time doing compile.

the problem is that there are many dart files

We need to reduce the dart file.
I built the release version and it was successful, leaving only the main files behind.

So the unnecessary dart file was erased and the build was successful.

But I don't think this is a fundamental solution.
I will continue to develop and make dart files. Then you'll face a situation where you don't build again.

Answer (score -1):

You need to run "flutter build ios" before use the code in Xcode

Check the docs: https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/ios

Comment: Use of `flutter build ios` is not a pre-condition. It's just an option if you want to prepare the build via command line.